# Ubuntu 20 Realtek audio combo jack external mic not being detected

Tags: sound, microphone, realtek, audio-jack

Hai I have realtek audio device and combojack on my laptop. No matter what I do it is not detecting microphones plugged into through the combojack. It keeps using the internal mic of the laptop. I even tried using a trrs connector and then plugging in a lavaliar mic along with a mic-less headphone.
In Pavucontrol it does not show the mic as an input device. Please help. I am having to switch to windows everytime i need to record audio.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue for a few weeks and I found that the problem was that I had selected the wrong mode / audio profile. I use XUbuntu, but this should apply to vanilla Ubuntu. The correct profile is `Analogue Stereo Duplex`. In my case, the wrong one was `Analogue Stereo Output` which disables the inputs. I have the feeling I selected this by mistake once I plugged my laptop to an external monitor.

To fix it

- Open a terminal and run `pavucontrol`.
- Go to the `Configuration` tab.
- Select the profile `Analogue Stereo Duplex`.

I hope this fixes the issue for you!